# Sum of different combinations.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I was trying to find the simplified form of ${100 \choose 0} + {100 \choose 1} + \ldots + {100 \choose 99} + {100 \choose 100}$. I was having a hard time finding a simple way to express the solution and I did not know how to do so without writing out the complete number. Does know what form I have to use?

Comment: It is equal to $2^{100}$.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to see it's $2^{100}$. There's a combinatorial argument, a pictorial argument via Pascal's triangle, or an identity based argument.

Answer (score 1):

The prior commenters have the correct answer of $2^{100}$. Here are some of my favorite proofs of this fact:

Firstly, using the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),
$$2^{100} = (1 + 1)^{100} = \sum_{i=0}^{100}{100\choose i}1^i1^{100-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{100}{100\choose i}$$

A combinatorial proof of this fact is counting the number of ways we can paint $100$ objects either black or white. One way to count this is to make a binary choice for each ball to paint it black or to paint it white, so this number is $2^{100}$. The other way is to choose $i$ elements to be painted white, and let $i$ range over all possible values. This gives the value as $\sum_{i=0}^{100}{100\choose i}$. Thus, these two quantities are equal to each other.